Validar edad en formulario
Código para validar una edad válida en un formulario
tengo este código para validar que se introducen enteros
    def validar_edad():
           
        entrada = input("Edad: ")  
        try:
            edad = int(entrada)
            return edad
        except ValueError:
            print("Por favor, ingrese una edad válida.") 

pero quiero validar que no se introducen más de dos dígitos

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Pobre si alguien tiene 101 años.. en fin... y que te impide agregar un if?

Solo necesitas añadir un if que compruebe que la edad esta en el rango deseado, por ejemplo:
def validar_edad() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            edad = int(input("Edad: "))
            if edad not in range(1, 99):
                print("Por favor, ingrese una edad valida")
                continue
            return edad
        except ValueError:
            print("Por favor, ingrese una edad valida")


Funciona, pero es un código poco eficiente porque Python tendrá que crear un generador range(1, 99) y luego verificar si existe el dato en él, por cada ciclo del while. Si bien, es un simple programa de entrada de usuario y "no importa mucho"; pero imagínate que fuera una validación automática para millones de datos, el tiempo y esfuerzo de procesamiento podría ser muy importante. Resulta mejor usar los comparadores clásicos: (edad >= 0) and (edad <= 99).

@aeportugal En Python también podría ser if 0 <= edad <= 99: o no ?

@Excorpion correcto, y lo mencionan en la documentación; es válido, aunque no sea bonito.
